# Intuition behind the definition of “long run propensity” equaling sum of coefficients?

Tags: regression

In a multiple linear regression model with independent variables x(t), x(t-1), x(t-2), etc. and dependent variable y, the “long run propensity” is defined to be the sum of beta coefficients in the entire model.

I don't understand this definition, can someone explain the logic behind this please?

Comment: In the way the question is worded now you’re asking for the proof of a definition, that doesn’t make sense.

Comment: Sorry for my English. I mean please explain to me why this logically makes sense to define in this way. Thank you.

Comment: I made an edit, what do you think?

Comment: I think it is great! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking at models such as

$$y_t = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_t + \beta_1 x_{t-1} + \ldots + \beta_n x_{t-n} + \varepsilon.$$

Suppose you gather some data and estimate a model and find:

$\beta_0 = 0,\, \beta_1 = 1,\, \beta_2 = -\frac{2}{3},\, \beta_3 = \frac{1}{3}$ and $\beta_n = 0$ for $n > 3$, that is
$$\hat{y}_t = x_t - \frac{2}{3} x_{t-1} +\frac{1}{3} x_{t-2}.$$

According to the definition, the Long Run Propensity is
$$1-\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{3}=\frac{2}{3}.$$

Why is this number interesting? That depends on the model, a simple example:

Suppose that $y_t$ is the change in GDP. This implies that in the long run a one time increase of $x_t$ of one unit implies an increase in GDP of $\frac{2}{3}$, an increase of $1$ on $t$, an increase compared to baseline of $\frac{1}{3}$ on $t+1$ and an increase of $\frac{2}{3}$ on $t+2$ and ever after.